# SELECT with SUM of a COUNT of distinct String

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

Data looks like:

```
ItemID | Customer# | Order# |  Salesman
 ITEM1     123         555       GUY1
 ITEM2     123         555       GUY1
 ITEM3     123         556       GUY1
 ITEM1     123         557       GUY3
 ITEM2     123         558       GUY2
 ITEM3     222         559       GUY4
```

Desired result should have unique Customer# and Count unique Order#s of each Salesman of that customer:

```
Customer# | GUY1 | GUY2 | GUY3 | GUY4 | TOTAL
   123       2       1      1     0       4
   222       0       0      0     1       1
```

**UPDATE**

This query works, but why do I have to add the minus one (-1) at the end to make it work?

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(IF(SALESMAN = 'GUY1', ORDER#, 0)))-1 AS 'GUY1',
    --More salesmen
    COUNT(DISTINCT (ORDER#)) AS Total
FROM
    TABLE
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array)

Comment: @Strawberry I had thought about doing that.  If we cannot find a resolution than I will be forced to utilize PHP for somewhat of a simple query.

Comment: It's better that way; more scalable and flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query to this

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
    SUM(IF(SALESMAN = 'GUY1', 1, 0)) AS 'GUY1',
    SUM(IF(SALESMAN = 'GUY2', 1, 0)) AS 'GUY2',
    --more case statements for salesman
    (COUNT(DISTINCT (ORDER#))) AS Total
FROM
    TABLE
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

But be careful. If you have huge table or a lot of salesmen - this query will slow down your system

Updated query:

```
SELECT 
    t.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
    SUM(IF(t.SALESMAN = 'GUY1', 1, 0)) AS 'GUY1',
    SUM(IF(t.SALESMAN = 'GUY2', 1, 0)) AS 'GUY2',
    --more case statements for salesman
    (COUNT(t.ORDER#)) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ORDER#, SALESMAN
        FROM TABLE
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ORDER#, SALESMAN) t
GROUP BY t.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

That should work

Comment: This is my initial problem.  This works but it doesn't count Unique ORDER#'s.  It is essentially counting every row, so in the above example, GUY1 would have 3 instead of the desired 2 result.

Comment: So group by ORDER# first, and then by CUSTOMER_NUMBER. `GROUP BY ORDER#, CUSTOMER_NUMBER`

Comment: I had thought this would work as well, however the `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` is now not unique and spits out row after row of the same `CUSTOMER_NUMBERS`

Comment: Right... Of course... change the group order `GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ORDER#`. This way each customer will have as many rows, as distinct orders he has... and then the query will count salesemen.

Comment: Right :( In that case no choice - use subqeury as 'FROM'. `from (SELECT CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ORDER#, SALESMAN FROM TABLE GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ORDER#, SALESMAN) `. So its like GROUP on GROUPED query :)

Comment: Please see my last update to question, I got it to work but it doesn't seem right?

Comment: I've updated my post. the query with two group by should do the trick

Comment: Just noticed your comment where you say that there's no other choice than to use a subquery. Actually, as you can see from my answer, it is possible to avoid a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

> This query works, but why do I have to add the minus one (-1) at the end to make it work?

Actually no, your query doesn't always work correctly, but you'll be able to see that for yourself after learning how it works (including the reason for the minus one).

First, let's see what kind of result these IF expressions return for a non-aggregated set. Using the data sample in your question and the `GUY1` expression only, we'll get this:

```
ItemID  Customer#  Order#  Salesman  IF(SALESMAN = 'GUY1', ORDER#, 0)
------  ---------  ------  --------  --------------------------------
ITEM1   123        555     GUY1      555
ITEM2   123        555     GUY1      555
ITEM3   123        556     GUY1      556
ITEM1   123        557     GUY3      0
ITEM2   123        558     GUY2      0
ITEM3   222        559     GUY4      0
```

You can see that for `Customer# = 123` the IF expression has three distinct values: 555, 556 and 0. The `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` over that expression would therefore return 3. However, the correct answer for `GUY1` should be 2. It is the 0 that distorts the result. This is why the `- 1` is used: it adjusts the result of `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` back to normal.

However, the adjustment is not always needed. More specifically, it is not needed when we are counting distinct orders for a salesman that is the only one for a certain customer. Your example actually contains such a case: there is only one salesman, `GUY4`, for customer `222`. Your expected output shows 1 under `GUY4` for the `222` row, but in actual fact [your query should return 0 there](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72d201/2), i.e. the output would be this:

```
Customer# | GUY1 | GUY2 | GUY3 | GUY4 | TOTAL
   123       2       1      1     0       4
   222       0       0      0     0       1
```

It is easy to fix the issue if we remember the fact that COUNT doesn't count NULLs. Just use that fact in your IF expressions: use NULL instead of 0 to omit non-relevant orders. And, of course, you'll need to get rid of the `- 1` adjustments. [This query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72d201/4) will return correct results consistently:

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(SALESMAN = 'GUY1', ORDER#, NULL)) AS GUY1,
    --More salesmen
    COUNT(DISTINCT (ORDER#)) AS Total
FROM
    `TABLE`
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NUMBER
;
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for clarifying the reason I needed NULL instead of zero.